# PHP - Regular expression to convert width/height attribute in style

Tags: php, regex

I need to change in styles all occurencies of width and height attributes in table/td/tr/th tags.

For example,

```
<table width="500" height="235" style="color:#FF0000;">
<tr>
<td width="30" height="25" style="color:#FFFF00;">Hello</td>
<td>World</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

should become

```
<table style="color:#FF0000;width:500px;height:235px"> 
<tr>
<td style="color:#FFFF00;width:30px;height:25px">Hello</td>
<td>World</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

how can I do it ?

Comment: [Thou shalt not use regular expressions to meddle with (X)HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: `style="red"` is major nonsense. Please clean up your example code.

Comment: @Linus [Thou shalt not link to that question because it is wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231382/regular-expression-pattern-not-matching-anywhere-in-string/4234491#4234491)

Comment: @Gordon I shall [link here next time then](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html).

Comment: @Linus yes, that's better. Or link to *(shameless self plug ahead)* [Best methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Comment: @Gordon I upvoted this answer and shall use it for further linking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without using regular expression (i.e.: the proper way):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$nodes = $xpath->query('//*[@width or @height]');

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $style = $node->getAttribute('style');
    $width = $node->getAttribute('width');
    $height = $node->getAttribute('height');
    $node->removeAttribute('width');
    $node->removeAttribute('height');

    $style = !empty($style) ? "$style;" : '';
    if (!empty($width)) $style .= "width:{$width}px;";
    if (!empty($height)) $style .= "height:{$height}px;";

    $node->setAttribute('style', $style);
}
```

**Note:** `red` is not a valid CSS attribute. You probably meant `color: red` or `background-color: red`, for which the following would convert... change:

```
$style = !empty($style) ? "$style;" : '';
```

to...

```
$style = !empty($style) ? "color: $style;" : '';
```

Comment: You should put the `;` before the additional `style` value.

Comment: @Gumbo: Oops, cut/paste (instead of copy/paste) in my edit, fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so this would be better suited to a parser, but if you can guarantee that order of the attributes, this may work...

```
preg_replace('/<(table|td|tr|th)\s+width="(\d+?)"\s+height="(\d+?)"/',
             '<$1 style="width: $2; height: $3"',
             $str);
```

I left out the stuff which didn't make sense, as [ThiefMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298479/thiefmaster) said in the comments.