# How to replace width="" and height="" of youtube embed with class="" instead?

Tags: php, html

I want to replace `width="" height=""` of Youtube embed code width `class="youtube"` instead so that I can set new width and height of Youtube embed with `class="youtube"` in CSS

I searched for PHP `str_replace()`, `preg_replace()` but I still don't know much that they are right to use or do I have to use another function.

Change this :

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

To this :

```
<iframe class="youtube" src="http://" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`
```

Comment: use domdocument instead or other html parser

Comment: are you trying to make the video responsive or something else?

Comment: yes,I try to show youtube width and height different in screen size..

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: I am so sorry.I will be more careful next time.Thank you for your advice and support.

Comment: This answer is worth a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4959046/2943403 It should be simple enough to modify for your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't know width or height so you can't use str_replace but preg_replace can solve problem

```
$newEnbedCode = preg_replace('/width="([0-9]+)" height="([0-9]+)"/', 'class="youtube"', $embedCode);
```

[working example](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/lBy)